# All computer programs consist of two elements: code and data

Tags: java

All computer programs consist of two elements: code and data. 
what is exactly code and data? 
i new to programming languages i want with more precise explanation with example.

Answer (score 1):

Code refers to source code is the set of instruction that place the needed logic for an specific purpose, it is the collection of classes that are used to execute a program.

Data refers to input/output information, in order to execute the instructions above you should use some kind of input information to make something in the process, also you expect and the end of the execution an output .

Think like a box, code is the box and data is what you put in and out of that box .

Answer (score 0):

**Code** lines of Statements in Programming Language.Which save in any laguage format.
e.g .java , .c ,.ccp or .js etc

Answer (score 0):

Code is instructions that tell the computer what to do.

Data is information that the computer applies those instructions to.

More detail and examples is sorta out-of-scope for Stack Exchange; a basic tutorial in programming will answer it for you.

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }

}
```

In this example the string literal `"Hello, World"` is the data.  The rest is code.

Answer (score 0):

To pull in a real life example: when you open your favourite word processor, then you're opening a piece of software that was written with code in one or another language. It has pieces of code that instruct how to load files, save files, print files, how to display files on your screen. It has code to render menus and toolbars and what have you. This is all code.

Then you tell your word processor to open a document. This document is data. You edit the document, that is, you bang on your keyboard so new words form new sentences in new chapters. This is also data.